# Find word in sentence with Bourne Shell (sh)

Tags: shell, shell-script, string, regular-expression

I'm trying to determine if a particular word appears in a sentence using Bourne Shell (sh). For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'

if [[ "$INPUT" == *dolor* ]]
then
    echo "So true"
else
    echo "Not true"
fi
```

This works in `bash`, but I can't use `bash`, I need something that works in `sh`

Comment: probably this doesn't work since `*` is the globbing operator responsible for file name expansion (this way it won't work in bash either)!? Why don't you want to use other `unix` standard tools (sed, awk, perl...)?

Comment: Your title was sh, but your script was running by bash. Which one?

Comment: Is it actually *Bourne* shell? Not `ash` or `dash`? Not `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh` running in `sh` compatibility mode? What's the actual operating system release you're using/targeting?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you meant POSIX shell syntax instead of Bourne shell as the Bourne shell is becoming quite a rare dinosaur these days.

Anyway, the answer is the same in both cases:

```
case $INPUT in
  *dolor*) echo true;;
  *) echo false;;
esac
```

The last `;;` before `esac` is not required. The POSIX syntax also allows `(*dolor*)`.

Comment: +1. probably need to quote `"$INPUT"` in the case statement

Comment: No, it's a rare case where you don't need to quote $INPUT (there can't be word splitting or filename generation there) but it does not harm to quote it.

Comment: I know that's true in bash, but in a POSIX shell?

Comment: Well yes, what effect would you expect if it weren't quoted? It can't split into words as there's only one string expected. It will not _go away_ if $INPUT is empty. Quotes are needed in list contexts, or potentially for $* for some shells when in non-list contexts.

Comment: @glennjackman `bash` is following the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05): the `case` statement does not do any word splitting on `$INPUT`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use other tools:

- `grep`: `if echo "$INPUT" | grep --quiet '\bdolor\b'`

Comment: Note that a system that has a Bourne shell is very unlinkely to have a grep that supports `\b` (GNUism). The `-w` flag is slightly more portable, but anyway the OP didn't ask to match whole words.

Comment: The title says "Find word"; I assumed that was the goal.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to match whole words portably, first, you need to define how words are delimited. If we go for GNU grep `-w`'s definition, then a word is a sequence of letters, numbers or underscore (and a delimiter would be any character that is not any of those). Unfortunately, the definition of "letter" is locale-dependant. POSIX shells can specify letters (with [[:alpha:]], but I don't know of any variant of the Bourne shell that does. So with a POSIX shell, you could do:

```
word_delimiter='[![:alnum:]_]'
case +$INPUT+ in
 (*${word_delimiter}dolor${word_delimiter}*) echo true;;
 (*) echo false;;
esac
```

And in the Bourne shell, you would have to assume US letters:

```
word_delimiter='[!a-zA-Z0-9_]'
case +$INPUT+ in
  *${word_delimiter}dolor${word_delimiter}*) echo true;;
  *) echo false;;
esac
```

Other options:

```
if
  tr -cs '[:alnum:]_' '[\n*]' << EOF | grep -qx dolor
$INPUT
EOF
then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi
```

While that syntax is POSIX, if you have to deal with as old a system as one having a Bourne shell, you may have issues with that "tr" syntax as there used to be two main variants of it in the old pre-POSIX days.

Comment: If you assume US letters, I'd recommend forcing `LC_ALL=C` for the duration of the script.  Otherwise character ranges like `[A-Z]` are very locale-dependent.

Comment: Well, if the shell supports locales (but here I was adding this part for the Bourne shell which generally doesn't), then it's good because A-Za-z is likely to match letters in the current locale. If the shell doesn't support locales, then well it will only match ASCII a-zA-Z and not other letters in your locale, but that would be the best you can do. Now it's true that `LC_ALL=C` would guarantee the same behavior in all shells (except those buggy ones where `LC_*` must be set at the time of teh shell invocation to be effective).